# Need to get cell value and declare it to the row range automatically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Name manager using `vba` ...
I need to get the cell value from the column one by one and have to declare that name to that row range next to that column

Example

In column **`D`** I have the name list

I have to get that D1 value and declare that value to the row range `( E1:S1 )`

Next

have to `D2 ---> E2:S2`

Comment: You mean you want to copy the value of `D1` to `E1:S1`?

Comment: @KenS. I think OP speaks about the named ranges.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be done for first 5 rows:

```
For i = 1 To 5
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=yourWorksheet.Cells(i, 4).Value, RefersTo:=yourWorksheet.Range(yourWorksheet.Cells(i, 5), yourWorksheet.Cells(i, 19))
Next
```

remember that the names must be unique

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
Sub AddNamedRange()
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")  'change Sheet4 to your sheet name
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row    'last row with data in Column D
        For Each cel In .Range("D1:D" & lastRow)     'loop through all cell in Column D
            ThisWorkbook.Names.Add cel, ws.Range(cel.Offset(, 1), cel.Offset(, 15)) 'adding named range
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```